# How to query JSON format in HIVE?

Tags: sql, json, hive

I have a JSON format data in HIVE, something like this:
{"space":"5200xx","app":"tech111","profile":"xx11","date":"2020-10-10"}
{"space":"5212xy","app":"olive111","profile":"222","date":"2021-04-10"}

How can I query this in HIVE? If I want to query just the date column?

```
DATE:
2020-10-10
2021-04-10
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: how do you have the data in hive? can you be more explicit?

Answer (score 0):

How about using `get_json_object()` like below.

```
select get_json_object('{"space":"5200xx","app":"tech111","profile":"xx11","date":"2020-10-10"}','$.date')
```

[image: Screenshot]

Now, if you want datetime field you can use
`from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(<<above string>>,'yyyy-MM-dd')) as timestamp_col`.